# on measuring XACML PDP performance exactly time taken to evaluate an access control request

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

How can I measure the XACML PDP performance using WSO2 exactly time taken to evaluate an access control request? Is it possible to do that using Apache Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not any different from measuring the performance of any application.

In XACML specifically you need to measure:

1. PEP-PDP call
2. PDP evaluation (including serialization / deserialization of XACML requests / responses)
3. PDP-PIP calls